# Python remove inner items of a sequence in a list

Tags: python

```
foo = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
bar = [x if x==0 else 'o' for x in foo]
```

bar:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0,'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
```

I would like to remove the inner 'o' at this point so that the result looks like so:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 'o','o', 0, 0, 0, 'o','o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
```

If possible, I'd like to do this within the list comprehension itself, and I would like to avoid anything with converting to a string (as my actual task for this involves dictionaries rather than 1's and 0's). Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you only have 1 `o` I assume you keeping it ?

Comment: Okay ... so the problem is to reduce any sequence of `1`s to simply `'o', 'o'`?  Is there some reason to need this within a list comprehension?  I expect that `regex` could do a neat job on the string of characters.

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, keep a single o if it is in the list

Comment: @Prune not quite...'o' is going to be a dictionary.  Trying a lists comprehension to keep it clean and short but if there's some clean solutions that are outside of a list comprehension, that's fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## By keeping track of the previous and next element

We can perform a check on the previous and next element, and check if these are `'o'`s as well, if so, we do *not* yield the element, otherwise we do, like:

```
nbar1 = len(bar) - 1
[ x for i, x in enumerate(bar) if not (0 < i < nbar1 and bar[i] == bar[i-1] == bar[i+1] == 'o') ]
```

The above can be made more elegant by using `chain` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

prev = chain((None,), bar)
nxt = islice(chain(bar, (None, )), 1, None)
result = [ x for p, x, n in zip(prev, bar, nxt) if not (p == x == n == 'o') ]
```

where `p` is the "previous item", `x` is the "current item", and `n` is the "next item".

This ten yields:

```
>>> [ x for p, x, n in zip(prev, bar, nxt) if not (p == x == n == 'o') ]
[0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o']
```

The above will also work with elements that are not `0`s, for example:

```
>>> bar = [1, 3, 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 'o', 2, 0, 'o', 'o']
>>> prev = chain((None,), bar)
>>> nxt = islice(chain(bar, (None, )), 1, None)
>>> [ x for p, x, n in zip(prev, bar, nxt) if not (p == x == n == 'o') ]
[1, 3, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 2, 0, 'o', 'o']
```

We can also easily change it to work with another element (than `'o'`), as long as it is not something that is equal to `None`. If that is the case, we can however chain other elements to the `prev` and `nxt` iterables.

The above works in linear time *O(n)* with *n* the length of the list to process.

## By grouping and slicing

An alternative is to use `itertools.groupby` to detect "bursts" of characters, and in case the burst contains `'o'`s, we `islice(..)` up to two elements:

from itertools import groupby, islice

```
[ x for k, g in groupby(bar) for x in (islice(g, 2) if k == 'o' else g) ]
```

again yielding:

```
>>> [ x for k, g in groupby(bar) for x in (islice(g, 2) if k == 'o' else g) ]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with one comprehension list:

```
bar=[x if x==0 else 'o' for i,x in enumerate(foo) if (i==0 or i==len(foo)-1) or x==0 or 
foo[i-1]==0 or foo[i+1]==0]
```

should work for your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> foo = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [ext for c, grp in groupby(foo) for ext in (grp if c==0 else ['o']*min(2,len(list(grp))))]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby` if `k` is `0` we append all the items from that group, if `k` is `'o'` we only append the first and last excluding the middle `'o'`'s

```
from itertools import groupby

bar = [0, 0, 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
new = []
for k, g in groupby(bar):
    x = list(g)
    if k == 0:
        for i in x:
            new.append(i)
    elif k == 'o':
        new.append(x[0])
        new.append(x[-1])

print(new)
# [0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o', 0, 0, 'o', 'o']
```